# Only print out strings from a list that contain certain characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume following list

```
my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']
```

I want to write a function that takes two parameters as the input
where m are the characters as a string that I want to find (e.g. 'ff') and n is the number of strings as an integer that I want to output.

So `def contains_strings('ff', 2):`

should output:

```
['coffee', 'insufficient']
```

Both words contain 'ff' and the output is 2 in total. The second parameter can be random. So I don't care if the function outputs. ['coffee', 'insufficient'] or ['differential', 'insufficient']

I was only able to write a function that is able to output words that start with certain characters:

```
import random as _random

my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']

def starting_letters(m: str, n: int):
    a = list(filter(lambda x: x.lower().startswith(m), my_list)) 
    print(_random.choices(a, k=n))
```

```
starting_letters('c', 2)
```

Output:

```
['coffee', 'cat']
```

Comment: why not use `in` ?

Comment: `a = list(filter(lambda x: m in x, my_list)) `?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Okay, that was kinda dump from me. I only had to remove the .startswith() Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
import random as _random

my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']

def contains_strings(m: str, n: int):
      a = list(filter(lambda x: m in x.lower(), my_list)) 
      return _random.sample(a, k=n)

print(contains_strings('ff', 2))

#['coffee', 'insufficient']
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use sample() instead of choices() `return _random.sample(a, k=n)`, because choices() can pick the same element pick before like  `['coffee', 'coffee']` which will be incorrect.

Comment: sample() is also random function

Comment: Yeah, @sittering is kinda right. Can you replace .choices with .sample and I mark the answer as the correct one

Comment: No problem, just note .sample will throw an error though if n is bigger than a. For example `print(contains_strings('tt', 2))` will return one element (bottle) and if n is 2 for example, you will get an error.

Comment: @MaximilianFreitag   add one condition,  `if len(a)<n: n=len(a)    print(f"{len(a)} words contains {m}")`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
import random as _random

my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']

def starting_letters(m: str, n: int):
    a = list(filter(lambda x: m in x.lower(), my_list)) 
    print(_random.sample(a, n))
```

Notice how I replaced the `random.choices()` method with the `random.sample()` method. The reason is because with the `random.choices()` method, you may get the element from the same index multiple times in the output, whereas the `random.sample()` method ensures that every returned element is from a unique index of the list.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I also noticed this. All of the sudden the function's output was twice the same word. The user AloneTogether also corrected this .sample(). Nevertheless take my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` here to match patterns in strings

```
import re
import random as _random

my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']


def contains_pattern(pattern: str, n: int):
    regex = re.compile(f'{pattern}')
    a = [ans for ans in my_list if regex.search(ans)]
    return _random.choices(a, k=n)

print(contains_pattern("ff",2))

# ['insufficient', 'coffee']
```

Answer (score 0):

import random as _random

my_list = ['bottle', 'coffee', 'insufficient', 'differential', 'cat']

def starting_letters(m: str, n: int):
a = list(filter(lambda x:  m in x, my_list))
print(_random.choices(a, k=n))

starting_letters('ff',2)